# wxWebView and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, youtube, wxwidgets, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to write a program in C++ and wxWidgets that accesses YouTube and start the video with JavaScript.

It uses the YouTube JavaScript API, documentation for which is found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

I wrote the following piece of code to play ‘O, Canada’, specifically the [one here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwDvF0NtgdU).

```
wxWebView *webview = wxWebView::New(this, wxID_ANY, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwDvF0NtgdU");
webview->RunScript("function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {document.getElementById('watch-player').playVideo();}");
```

Running the above code fails to fulfill its intended purpose, giving me the following error and a crash:

> ....\src\msw\wxwebview_ie.cpp(762): "assert "document" failed in wxWebViewIE::GetDocument().

I know that my code successfully LOADS the page, but running the JavaScript (the `RunScript()` function) seems to result in the error.

I am using wxWidgets 2.9.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually because I call the JavaScript too early, before the page is loaded. If I call it a bit later, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should have been fixed in [revision 71030](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/71030/wxWidgets) which is more recent than the 2.9.3 build that you are using. You can get the updated code either through [SVN](http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/svn.htm) or a daily [snapshot](http://biolpc22.york.ac.uk/pub/Daily_HEAD/). If that still doesn't fix it please file a bug on the wxWidgets [Trac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/).

Comment: Upgrading did fix the crash, but the js isn't ran at all. I replaced the js with a simple alert() and no window poped up.